# Why is SHA-1 considered insecure?

Tags: hash, cryptography

Microsoft, google and mozilla have decided not to accept it in 2017 because of the flaws found by researchers. And I saw SHA-1 is depreciated nearly everywhere simply because people think that it's not safe anymore. But unlike MD5, currently there is no known collision found on SHA-1. And even the fastest algorithm for the collision of SHA-1 still requires nearly 2^60 evaluations, which is still a very large number.

My question is why SHA-1, a hash algorithm which hasn't been found any collisions and which still requires a large amount of time to find a collision, is depreciated? I understand SHA-2 is more secure, but it is also slower than SHA-1, why most people recommend to trade performance for the so-called "security" where the security of SHA-1 is not even an issue for most situations?

Comment: maybe interesting? [Schneier on Security - SHA-1 Broken](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html). Also: http://news.softpedia.com/news/sha1-algorithm-could-become-useless-by-the-end-of-the-year-494097.shtml

Comment: It is a 'good hash algorithm' to use for hashing strings. It is fast and unlikely to generate collisions. However, it is no longer 'cryptographically secure'. [see](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/sha1-crypto-algorithm-securing-internet-could-break-by-years-end/) ;-/

Comment: It is not "simply because people think that it's not safe anymore" but because world class cryptologists have determined that it has flaws and feel that attacks will only progress. That there is a good replacement that has been well vetted (the SHA-2 family). That we need to stop using it before it potentially becomes another MD5. OK, the argument to keep using SHA-1?

Comment: Also: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/10/when_will_we_se.html - When Will We See Collisions for SHA-1? " $2.77M in 2012 ... $43K by 2021. A collision attack is therefore well within the range of what an organized crime syndicate can practically budget by 2018, and a university research project by 2021."

Comment: Attributed by Bruce to the NSA: "Attacks only get better; they never get worse." Not entirely true, as sometimes theoretical attacks themselves are invalidated or mitigating circumstances are found, but the underlying idea is clear. If something is found to be broken, it's very possible that it is more broken than currently expected, that better attacks exist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is only about [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com), not programming.

Comment: Thanks for your information. My point is if it's safe currently, why trade performace for it? Seems the answer is that we want to avoid potential changes in the future if it's really broken at some time, so we want to give it up now?@zaph @Ryan

Comment: The future is rather sooner than we would like. Sadly, performance is the issue. If something is 'efficient' then someone with a 'really powerful machine' can try _lots more possibilities_ tham a slow calculation. Ok, Not a problem if perfect. Alas, it turns out that you can bypass a lot of the internal processing that the original code does - **but still get the same results** (collisions) ;-/. not good?

Comment: You cloud find that [sha1](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/hash/sha1/) output has smaller bits than [sha2](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/hash/sha256/) does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHA-1 is weak because of collision attacks:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Attacks

> In an interview, Yin states that, "Roughly, we exploit the following two weaknesses: One is that the file preprocessing step is not complicated enough; another is that certain math operations in the first 20 rounds have unexpected security problems."

---

https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html

> collisions in the the full SHA-1 in 2^69 hash operations, much less
>   than the brute-force attack of 2^80 operations based on the hash
>   length.
>
> collisions in SHA-0 in 2^39 operations.
>
> collisions in 58-round SHA-1 in 2^33 operations.

there is a collision attack on SHA-1's compression function that requires only 2^57 SHA-1 evaluations